# Is it possible to capture this nil pointer error

Tags: go

I had a "nil pointer" bug that the compiler can't find out, but I'd like to see if there is a way to find it out by statically analyze it.

So the bug is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    name string
}

func newGoodA() (*A, error) {
    return &A{
        name: "Go",
    }, nil
}

func newBadA() (*A, error) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create A")
}

func (a *A) greet() string {
    return "Hello " + a.name
}

func main() {
    valueA, err := newBadA()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Oops, failed because: %v", valueA.greet()) // This should be forbidden, because when err is not nil, valueA shouldn't be touched
    }
}
```

When I run it, I had error, because `valueA` is `nil`.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

This is a common mistake, but the compiler can't find out. I wonder if there is any tool that can statically analyze the code and find this out.

I feel it's possible if the rule is that:

If a function call returns a value and an error, then the `if err != nil` logic should not touch that returned value (`valueA` in this example), because that's dangerous, and most likely to be `nil`.

Is there any tool can do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ... btw it is possible to capture this kind of error without any additional tooling. Simply unit test your code and you should be good.

Comment: A non-nil error return does not necessarily imply that the other return values are dangerous, nil or invalid in some way.  It's usually the case, but not always.

Comment: Your code does not panic: https://play.golang.org/p/u6TDUJN4SwF

Comment: I think you meant to call `newBadA` in your example above.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct to say that you cannot use valueA even if it is nil in the case of an error being returned by newBadA. Go will happily invoke the function on the nil receiver - for example:

```
func (a *A) greet() string {
   if a == nil {
      return "(nil)"
   }
   return a.name
}
```